# How to properly convert java collection to Kotlin language

Tags: java, kotlin, collections

I'm pretty confused about kotlin collections, especially after reading official documents, I'm still got stuck. Besides, if I just copy paste java code into kotlin file, the auto-converted code seems not compatible.

```
List<List<command>> commandsList =
                commands.stream().map(this::rebuildCommand).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For this piece of code, how should I correctly write it in kotlin?

Comment: What does `commands` stands for? `List<Command>`?

Comment: This Java code really converts to exactly the same Kotlin code. Only the variable declaration changes to: `commandsList: List<List<command>>` (and we can remove `;` at the end). Besides that, it is identical. So if this doesn't work for you then I guess there is another problem in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy-pasting gives

```
val commandsList: List<List<command>> = commands.stream().map(this::rebuildCommand).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Which is valid Kotlin code. If you need it to be a MutableList in the end, you can modify the return type so it isn't upcasting to the read-only Kotlin List:

```
val commandsList: MutableList<MutableList<command>> = commands.stream().map(this::rebuildCommand).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

If you don't need it to be mutable, it's more efficient to do this without a Stream and Collector:

```
val commandsList: List<List<command>> = commands.map(this::rebuildCommand)
```

Comment: You could also use
     `commands.map(this::rebuildCommand).toMutableList()`
so that you don't use the java stream api and you still have a mutable list.